# Bootstrapper with custom package

Tags: msbuild, bootstrapper

I'm currently developping a bootstrapper to deploy one of my VSTO addins.

I thus created a prerequisites list before compiled it with MSBuild, but I also need to test and install the otkloadr.dll fix (KB907417). In a first time I used a custom bootstrapper package, but the package directory and files must be included with my deployment if I want to use it.
In fact I really want to have a very light setup kit, with only the setup.exe and the addin.msi files...

Is there a way to use a custom bootstrapper package embedded into the setup.exe ?
If not, is there a standard bootstrapper package which include the KB907417 fix ?

Answer (score 1):

I built one a quick sfx that unpacked all setup files to a temp directory, ran setup.exe, and deleted all files. I can't give it to you but it should take you no more than a day to replicate.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've done a simple SFX using winrar and it's working.